# editing .bashrc file

Tags: linux, python, bashrc

I finished installing Enthought's python EPD free, I got this note:

> ```
> As the last step, you should edit your .bashrc or prepend
> the EPD_free install path:
>
>     /home/zed/epdfree/bin
>
> Thank you for installing EPD_free!
> ```

how to edit my .bashrc and add that line?

Answer (score 3):

you simply have to open up your bashrc file with `nano  ~/.bashrc`. Add what you need to, and thats about it in this case

A more 'correct' way to do it would be to use `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/zed/epdfree/bin' >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: You can also edit ~/.bashrc with the text editor of your choice if you don't want to use nano. Eg mousepad ~/.bashrc will open it up in mousepad.