# How do I change the default python version in Red Hat 6?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, bashrc

I've recently installed Enthought Python Distribution, after which it gave me the message:

> As the last step, you should edit your .bashrc or prepend the EPD install path:
>
> /home/j.inglis/epd-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64/bin
>
> Thank you for installing EPD!

I read the answer to [editing .bashrc file](https://superuser.com/questions/507266/editing-bashrc-file) and did the `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/j.inglis/epd-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64/bin' >> ~/.bashrc`, then logged out, then back in.

However, typing `which python` gives me `/usr/local/bin/python` rather than the desired `/home/j.inglis/epd-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64/bin/python`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PATH is read starting at the front. So you need to get rid of the line you just added to your .bashrc file, and replace it with:

```
export PATH=/home/j.inglis/epd-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64/bin/python:$PATH
```

And it should work fine.

The other option would be to uninstall the version of python you do not want.